# CUDA kernel "Only a single pack parameter is allowed" workaround?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, cuda, variadic-templates

The CUDA 7 standard regarding variadic global function templates states ["only a single pack parameter is allowed."](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cpp11-global)  Is there an elegant workaround for this?  I want to be able to do something like:

```
template<int... vals>
void RecursiveFunct() {

}

template<int... vals, typename T, typename... Args>
void RecursiveFunct(T t, Args... args) {
  t.template call<vals...>();
  RecursiveFunct<vals...>(args...);
}
```

I'm thinking I could wrap my pack of integers into something before passing them along but is it possible to do that in a way that is transparent to the caller of this code?

Comment: Note that [clang](http://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html) can compile the CUDA language and unlike nvcc it does not have these ridiculous restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure to understand your exactly limits but... I suppose that `std::integer_sequence` and a wrapper function to call `call()` can help you.

The following is a toy, but compilable, example that show what I mean.

```
struct foo
 {
   template <int ... vals>
   void call () const
    { std::cout << "- call " << sizeof...(vals) << std::endl; }
 };

template <typename IS>
void RecursiveFunct (IS const &)
 { }

template <typename T, int ... vals>
void wrapCall (T const & t, std::integer_sequence<int, vals...> const &)
 { t.template call<vals...>(); }


template<typename IS,  typename T, typename ... Args>
void RecursiveFunct (IS const & is, T t, Args... args)
 {
   wrapCall(t, is);
   RecursiveFunct(is, args...);
 }

int main ()
 {
   // print 5 times "- call 4"
   RecursiveFunct(std::integer_sequence<int, 2, 3, 5, 7>{},
                  foo{}, foo{}, foo{}, foo{}, foo{});
 }
```

Take in count that `std::integer_sequence` is a C++14 feature, so the preceding code needs (at least) a C++14 compiler.

But if you need to work with C++11, it's trivial to create a `std::integer_sequence` substitute.

By example

```
template <typename T, T ... ts>
struct myIntegerSequence
 { };
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> can this work without creating an instance of integer_sequence?

In normal C++14, yes. Works this with Cuda? I don't know.

I've obtained this changing the `wrapCall()` func with a `wrapCall` struct and a `func()` static method. This because I've used the partial specialization that can't be used with funcs.

The folling is the toy example

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct foo
 {
   template <int ... vals>
   void call () const
    { std::cout << "- call " << sizeof...(vals) << std::endl; }
 };

template <typename>
void RecursiveFunct ()
 { }

template <typename>
struct wrapCall;

template <int ... vals>
struct wrapCall<std::integer_sequence<int, vals...>>
 {
   template <typename T>
   static constexpr void func (T const & t)
    { t.template call<vals...>(); }
 };

template<typename IS,  typename T, typename ... Args>
void RecursiveFunct (T t, Args... args)
 {
   wrapCall<IS>::func(t);
   RecursiveFunct<IS>(args...);
 }

int main ()
 {
   // print 5 times "- call 4"
   RecursiveFunct<std::integer_sequence<int, 2, 3, 5, 7>>
                  (foo{}, foo{}, foo{}, foo{}, foo{});
 }
```

But are you sure that is a problem the istantiation of a `std::integer_sequence`?

Comment: Thanks, this works for me!  Is the trick to have "int ... vals" in the template parameters and take "integer_sequence<int, vals...>" as an argument, or is that incidental?  In other words, can this work without creating an instance of integer_sequence?

Comment: @A_K - you're welcome; answer modified to respond to your last question.

Comment: Thanks again!  The partially-specialized class template method does work with Cuda.  The only troublesome case was calling functions that take zero template parameters; they are not function templates so "t.template call<vals...>()" doesn't work.  To handle this case (without constexpr if) I ended up putting the same function body but with a simple "t.call()" into the "template <typename>
struct wrapCall" declaration.  Then this version of wrapCall is called by a "BasicRecursiveFunct" that does not have an integer_sequence as a template parameter.  Only a little code duplication...